# SQLAlchemy db.create_all() demo fails

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am following the tutorial from this page:

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html

I believe I did it exactly line for line. But I get an error each time when I try to db.create_all()

Here is my code (I moved the actual db.create_all() to be part of the file for simplicity here, though I've tried it the way the tutorial shows as well at the command line.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

db.create_all()
```

I found a similar question on Stack Overflow at 
[Flask SQLAlchemy db.create_all() not creating database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648170/flask-sqlalchemy-db-create-all-not-creating-database)

and

[SQLAlchemy create_all() does not create tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744277/sqlalchemy-create-all-does-not-create-tables)

But that response didn't help me. (In fact the answer to the second one seems to have a serious bug)

This is all in Python 3.4

The error I get is very long, but here it is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 90, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 377, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import test_create_db.py
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\test_create_db.py", line 25, in <module>
    db.create_all()
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 895, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 887, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 3404, in create_all
    tables=tables)
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1615, in _run_visitor
    with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1608, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
    with self.contextual_connect() as conn:
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1798, in contextual_connect
    self.pool.connect(),
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 338, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 644, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 440, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1057, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 285, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 411, in __init__
    self.connection = self.__connect()
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 538, in __connect
    connection = self.__pool._creator()
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 96, in connect
    connection_invalidated=invalidated
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 188, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=exc_value)
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 181, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 90, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Programming\LearningFlask\FlaskCookbook\test_create_db\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 377, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) unable to open database file None None
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using Windows, and there is no `/tmp` temporary directory in Windows. The database connection fails because SQLite3 has no directory to create the database file in. Pick a different location for your database file.

In this case, you could use [`tempfile.gettempdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir) to build a path:

```
import tempfile
import os.path

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(
    tempfile.gettempdir(), 'test.db')
```

Comment: LOL. I ended up just doing: app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db' and that worked.

Comment: @BruceNielson: but take into account you are now putting the file in the current working directory, wherever that may be (it depends on how you start the process)