# Why does SQLAlchemy say that the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI was not set when testing in production with Pytest?

Tags: python, flask, pytest, github-actions, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask app that uses sqlalchemy, the app factory method, and the config.py approach to setting the app.config. I also have a CI pipeline that tests my app using pytest, this runs on a production server through a self hosted github runner. ALl the tests pass on my local machine, but when the run on the runner (on the server), sql alchemy throws an error saying that the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL was not set, when it surely was in the app factory. How should I trouble shoot??

`extensions.py`:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

# global state for DB connection
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
```

`__init__.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask
from app.blueprints.main import main
from app.blueprints.api import api
from flask_cors import CORS
from app.extensions import db, migrate

# application factory method used to create the flask app with all the blueprints and extensions
def create_app(config=None):
    #creates the app
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # set config
    if config is None:
        app.config.from_object('config.BaseConfig')
    else:
        app.config.from_object(config)
    
    #sets cors to accept everything
    CORS(app, resources={r"*": {"origins": "*"}})

    # init sql alchemy db
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
        
    #registers the blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    app.register_blueprint(api)

    #returns the app
    return app
```

`config.py`:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
load_dotenv()

# add app configs here, see __init__.py for how to use them

class BaseConfig(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")

    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv("SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI")
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

class TestingConfig(BaseConfig):
    TESTING = True
```

And here is my app fixture for pytest:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app("config.TestingConfig")
    return app
```

I think the problem stems from the fact that the tests are being run on the external server, but still the app should be created as normal, and the server has all the .env vars, so I'm not really sure where to look to troubleshoot

Here is the actual error from the GitHub Actions console:

```
        if not engine_options:
>           raise RuntimeError(
                "Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set."
            )
E           RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set.

../../_tool/Python/3.11.3/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py:307: RuntimeError
____________ ERROR at setup of test_FlightData_creates_successfully ____________

    @pytest.fixture
    def app():
>       app = create_app("config.TestingConfig")
```

Comment: _sql alchemy throws an error saying that the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL` was not set_ The `config.py` file is using `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`, not `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL`.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25648232/5320906)